# Slice a binary file into multiple files in python based on pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x, binaryfiles

I have a binary file. It has multiple lines but I cannot do readlines as the file is binary and also sometimes the newline is \r, \n, \r\n. The file looks like this

```
orange binarydata
binary data
binary data
orange binarydata
binary data
```

so I tried to write the regex but it fails to capture the last orange. I need to capture everything starting from orange until next orange or end of the file.

```
f = open("data.ir", "rb")
allSignal = f.read()
signalList = re.findall(b'(orange .*?)(orange)+', allSignal, re.DOTALL)

for line in (signalList):
    print(line[0])
```

but this fails to capture the last orange to the end of the file.
Let me know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach:

```
 orange(.*)(?=orange)|orange(.*)
```

[Regex101 Sample](https://regex101.com/r/7XUDqe/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just find the indexes of the two oranges, and slice out the middle bit?

```
with open('data.ir', 'rb') as f:
    all_signal = f.read()

orange1 = all_signal.index('orange')
orange2 = all_signal.index('orange', orange1)

if orange2 == -1:
    # second orange not found, read to end of file
    signals = all_signal[orange1:]
else:
    signals = all_signal[orange1:orange2+len('orange')]
print(signals)
```